# How to pass the field to list of child objects in "has a" relationship

Tags: c#, .net, oop, encapsulation

I have a class `Step`

```
public class TrainingStep
{
    private List<Part> parts;
    public Part currentPart;
   
    public void AddPart(Part part)
    {
       parts.Add(part);
    }

    ///a lot of public methods which are called from one layer above Step( a class containing Step list)
}
```

In this code the `Part` doesn't know anything about `Step`.

The `currentPart` is changing very often
and I want all of `parts` to know which is the current now

To achieve this I considered to add `step` as a parameter for `Part` class constructor, in order every part knows to which `Step` it belongs.
Something like this

```
public Part(Step step, ...)
{
  this.step = step;
}
```

But the problem of such kind of solution is that I can access every public method in `Step` class from `Part` using the reference which I've passed via constructor.

But I want to access only `currentPart` field from `Part`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: First encapsulate `currentPart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might define a `Func<Part>` which returns your `currentPart` and pass this delegate to your parts.

```
public class TrainingStep
{
    private List<Part> parts;
    public Part currentPart;
    private Func<Part> getCurrentPartFunc = () => currentPart;
   
    public void AddPart(Part part)
    {
       part.GetCurrentpart = getCurrentPartFunc;
       parts.Add(part);
    }
}

class Part
{
    public Func<Part> GetCurrentPart {get; set;}
}
```